# Generate Xcode Project from iOS App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, export, generator

Is there a way to create an app that generates an Xcode project that a developer can run in Xcode. Kind of like a code generator. I'm trying to look for answers in the web but to no avail. I'm also not sure where to start. Basically, the app will generate Xcode compatible codes which a developer can use to open to Xcode.

A sample application that's available in the AppStore that offers the same functionality is Interface for iOS. Link: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/interface/id360543182?mt=8

Another example is Dapp the App Creator:
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/dapp-app-creator-make-learn/id370888555?mt=8

From their app description:

*Xcode Export, Turn Your Mockup into Live Codes
Our free cloud based Xcode export service will convert your entire project into an Xcode project in just one single tap.*

*Dapp creates your complete Xcode Project for you - including code, images, videos and Xcode Storyboards!*

UPDATE: I was thinking of including a zip file of a sample Xcode project template file inside the app that will generate codes that will be used by the template project, edit or add them in the template project, zip and export to Documents folder thru iTunes File Sharing.

Comment: Generates a project from an existing app in the store? Containing more than just a name or some stolen resource files?

Comment: I can't see that the question was about generating a project from an existing app, only generating code and an XCode project. If the code you're generating is only basic you could just copy the contents created for you by XCode with a 'Single View Application' template, add your generated code from the app, then zip the contents and email or UIDocumentInteractionController them out to the user.

Comment: @Wain Not yet an existing app from the store but an app that I'll still be creating.

Comment: @Toby do you have a more detailed step by step guide on where I can start to generate the Xcode project that you've mentioned? That'll help me a lot. Basically, the app will handle everything from zipping up to saving the  zipped file in the app's Documents folder ready to be exported in iTunes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Open Xcode, create a new project, choose Single View Application (or something that best suits what you'll be generating) click create.
2. Go to the directory where this project was created, zip it and include it in the project for the App that will do the generating.
3. When it's time to generate the code, step 1 is to create a working directory and unzip the project to it.
4. Generate your classes etc. and put them into the directory where the AppDelegate.h and the other files generated for you from the Single View Application template are.
5. Open the xcodeproj package, at the root level there will be a file called project.pbxproj, read it into memory
6. Modify the project.pbxproj to include the generated code files, there will be a section called PBXFileReference where you can do this.

Here's an example PBXFileReference section from a project I had handy:

```
    /* Begin PBXFileReference section */
        DB6C03BA1B148F56007554E7 /* UIAlertController.app */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = wrapper.application; includeInIndex = 0; path = UIAlertController.app; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        DB6C03BE1B148F56007554E7 /* Info.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; path = Info.plist; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03BF1B148F56007554E7 /* main.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = main.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03C11B148F56007554E7 /* AppDelegate.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = AppDelegate.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03C21B148F56007554E7 /* AppDelegate.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = AppDelegate.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03C41B148F56007554E7 /* ViewController.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = ViewController.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03C51B148F56007554E7 /* ViewController.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = ViewController.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03C81B148F56007554E7 /* Base */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = file.storyboard; name = Base; path = Base.lproj/Main.storyboard; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03CA1B148F56007554E7 /* Images.xcassets */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = folder.assetcatalog; path = Images.xcassets; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03CD1B148F56007554E7 /* Base */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = file.xib; name = Base; path = Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03D31B148F56007554E7 /* UIAlertControllerTests.xctest */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = wrapper.cfbundle; includeInIndex = 0; path = UIAlertControllerTests.xctest; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        DB6C03D81B148F56007554E7 /* Info.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; path = Info.plist; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        DB6C03D91B148F56007554E7 /* UIAlertControllerTests.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = UIAlertControllerTests.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
/* End PBXFileReference section */
```

7. Write your changes to project.pbxproj (I imagine there may be more than simply the PBXFileReference depending on the complexity of what you're trying to achieve).
8. Zip the contents of your working directory for the project and email or UIDocumentInteractionController them out to the user.

This is a good article on the pbxproj file: http://danwright.info/blog/2010/10/xcode-pbxproject-files/

Comment: You just generated the code in xcode and copied it into your app. So your app is not generating the code, xcode is.

Comment: The boilerplate code generated by Xcode is only included as a kicking off point, you could always have the app write out the boilerplate code as well, but there's no point. Once you have the boilerplate, you can generate your own class files and then include them into the project as I've shown.

Comment: Thanks for this @Toby This is one way to start things off.

Comment: @Toby do you happen to have sample codes for this especially in steps 4 onwards?

Comment: @Toby I'm specifically curious as to how to edit header and implementation files from what you've discussed above without using Xcode and just using parameters generated from an iOS app itself.

Comment: @jaxtrixz I'll create an example and link it here, note that it's only going to deal with the creation of files, writing them to disk and then linking to them from the pbxproj file. Going in-depth about code generation would be out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

The app whose link you have posted is just used to create mockups. It does **not** generate code.

It is not possible to make an app that will generate code that you can later somehow import in xcode and run it.

Comment: I used Interface before and it generates code. It's even mentioned in their app description which I also posted above.

Comment: generates UI codes. Basically you'll still need Xcode to submit the generated codes to the AppStore. What if after is a simple template to start with.

Comment: I have to agree to that but not all functionality. Some can be pre-populated already especially for static actions

Comment: What is the limiting factor/s that makes it impossible for an app to generate code that could be imported into Xcode?